# TensorFlow/WaveGAN Failing To Detect Audio Files

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, speech-recognition, generative-adversarial-network

When I'm trying to train WaveGAN (https://github.com/chrisdonahue/wavegan) on Google Colaboratory, I keep getting this error message that goes as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/content/wavegan/train_wavegan.py", line 668, in <module>
    raise Exception('Did not find any audio files in specified directory')
Exception: Did not find any audio files in specified directory
```

This seems like a fairly straightforwards error but I'm directing WaveGAN towards a folder that contains .wav files downloaded from a Speech Command dataset archive (https://developer.ibm.com/data/speech-commands/) yet the program claims there are no audio files in that directory. What could I be doing wrong? Please advise.

Update: As per request, I've created a Google drive folder that contains screenshots of my colab dataset folder, the command I'm using to access the folder, and the code that displays the error I'm facing. Stack Overflow does not let me embed images.
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/16ozCywHHHw5G9KFw9qXqGx9MkN7_ZQ1s?usp=sharing

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: we have no access to you project, I suggest you to post an image/screenshot of the folders in colab, and to post the code that is trying to access it

Comment: I've edited the post to include a link to the relevant screenshots.